# How can I search by Timestamp in a android sqllite3 contentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp, android-contentprovider

i have a problem with a query in my custom contentProvider

i want to query my timestamp field (TaskDescriptor.DUE_DATE).

First i instanciate my Calendar object in this manner:

```
Calendar minorRange = Calendar.getInstance();
        minorRange.set(Calendar.HOUR, 00);
        minorRange.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        minorRange.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Calendar majorRange = Calendar.getInstance();
        majorRange.set(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
        majorRange.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        majorRange.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

then i query the contentprovider :

```
Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(TaskDescriptor.CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION, TaskDescriptor.DUE_DATE + " >= ? " + " AND " + TaskDescriptor.DUE_DATE + " <=?",
                        new String[] { minorRange.getTimeInMillis() + "", majorRange.getTimeInMillis() + ""}, TaskDescriptor.PRIORITY_SORT_ORDER);
```

The query run perfectly but don't retrieve any records... The Field are Timestamp.

Anyone know how can I do this ?

Thanks, Regards.

Antonio Musella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ... thanks all ... this query works fine ... i'm wrong .. it's only a maven refresh problem ! ... thanks all 
Regards.